# SQLAlchemy: how to make primary_key not unique (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I really need that. I've tried to define it in my model:

```
vs_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=False)
```

But it didn't work - database schema has such row:

> ALTER TABLE ONLY my_table__
>       ADD CONSTRAINT my_table___pkey PRIMARY KEY (vs_id);

How to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Primary key is by definition something that uniquely identifies rows.

Comment: And if you're trying to make it a primary key for the purpose of fast lookups consider using an index instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary key MUST be unique, in order to be able to refer to a specific record.

If you need this, add another field that isn't unique!